# How to extract Java Email body without auto wrapping every line to 76 chars

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, multipart, gmail-imap

I am trying to extract the body of the email using Java mail. When I try to extract the body of the email using the below code, the email wraps every line to 76 chars by appending new line char. 
I want the original email formatting with no wrapping of text. Here is the code I use to extract the text content of the email.

```
private static String getTextFromMessage(Message message) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        String result = "";
        if (message.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
            result = message.getContent().toString();
        } else if (message.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
            MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart) message.getContent();
            result = getTextFromMimeMultipart(mimeMultipart);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static String getTextFromMimeMultipart(
            MimeMultipart mimeMultipart)  throws MessagingException, IOException{
        String result = "";
        int count = mimeMultipart.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(i);
            if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
                result = result + bodyPart.getContent();
                break; // without break same text appears twice in my tests
            } else if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/html")) {
                String html = (String) bodyPart.getContent();
                result = result  + org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(html).text();
            } else if (bodyPart.getContent() instanceof MimeMultipart){
                result = result + getTextFromMimeMultipart((MimeMultipart)bodyPart.getContent());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Can someone provide a solution where I can get original email line lengths, without 76 char wrapping?

Comment: [RFC 5322](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-2.1.1) says that lines in an email should to be no more than 78 characters, including the trailing CRLF, so Javamail is correct to break lines when sending or to return the body lines at 76 characters. If you don't want that, use a different transfer encoding like quoted-printable. Then insert `=` as soft line break.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the content you can try to read the content using [javax.mail.Part::getInputStream](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Part.html#getInputStream--). Otherwise you can use [javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility::unfold](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html#unfold-java.lang.String-) to remove the line breaks on the returned content.

Answer (score 0):

JavaMail isn't inserting the line breaks.  The line breaks are there
in the original message and were inserted by the sending mailer.
There's many reasons the sending mailer might have inserted line
breaks, but without seeing an example of the MIME message content
that you're reading it's hard to know which case you're running in to.